# Measurable cardinals are weakly-compact?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

First off, this isn't homework, but I'm doing research into large cardinal stuff so I wanna understand these theorems.  I'm given this information to work with:

1. a cardinal $\mu$ is measurable if there exists a nonprincipal $\mu$-ultrafilter on $\mu$, that is, a nonprincipal ultrafilter that is closed under the intersection of $<\mu$-many sets in the filter.
2. a cardinal $\kappa$ is called weakly-compact if, for every complete total order $(C,<)$, if $|(C,<)|\ge\kappa$, then there exists a $B\subseteq C$ such that $|B|=\kappa$ and either $(B,\le)$ or $(B,\ge)$ is a well-order.

I am also given (and understand the proofs of) the facts that a topological space $X$ is compact iff every ultrafilter on $X$ converges, and that a total order $(X,<)$ is compact under the order topology iff $(X,<)$ is a complete order.

The two ways I see to do this are: 1. for a direct proof, constructing a well-order $(B,\le)$ or $(B,\ge)$ with $|B|=\mu$ from a non-principal $\mu$-ultrafilter, or for the contrapositive, 2. showing that if every $B\subseteq C$ is not a well-order under $\le$ nor $\ge$, then any $\mu$-ultrafilter on $\mu$ is principal.  Not entirely sure how to show either of these, however.  Any tips for how to approach this?

I do know that given a $\mu$-ultrafilter $\mathcal{F}$ and an injection $f:\mu\to C$, the set $\{f(A):A\in\mathcal{F}\}$ is a $\mu$-ultrafilter (I have verified this), so perhaps I could work with the $\mu$-ultrafilter ordered under inclusion, but again, not entirely sure until I try it.

Comment: What's wrong with the obvious argument? Suppose $C$ is totally ordered by $\lt$ and $|C|=\mu$ is a measurable cardinal. Consider a fixed nonprincipal $\mu$-complete ultrafilter on $C.$ For each $x\in C$ either almost all elements of $C$ are above $x$ or else almost all elements of $C$ are below $x$. Put $x\in A$ ($x\in B$) if almost all elements of $C$ are above (below) $x.$ Without loss of generality, almost all elements of $C$ are in $A.$ Now construct a strictly increasing sequence of length $\mu$ in $A.$

Comment: @bof: Why are you posting answers in the comments? :-)

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I have to ask though: where does nonprincipality come in?

Comment: @Xevrex For x in C, either almost all elements of C are greater than x, or almost all elements are less than x **or almost all elements are equal to x**. Nonprincipality comes in to rule out the third case.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It's safer to post comments, they can't be downvoted.